# TypeScript / Angular 2, what is a common data transforming pattern?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Writing an Angular 2+ application with TypeScript.

I'm modeling objects to save in a data source.  Some these objects have helper methods in them.  I save them no problem.
SAMPLE ORIGINAL CLASS DESIGN

```
export class Order {
    readonly orderNumber: string;
    amount: number;
    shortCode: string;
    readonly dateCreated: string;

    constructor(){
        this.orderNumber = cuid();
        this.dateCreated = moment().format();
    }

    incrementAmount(): void {
        this.amount += 1;
    }
```

SAMPLE RETURNED:

```
{ amount: 74.22,
  dateCreated: '2017-04-03T21:23:49-04:00',
  orderNumber: 'cj12v2rf50000zoguviraoik9',
  shortCode: 'SJLLDE' }
```

Now when i retrieve them they're not in original object form.  It seems very anti JavaScript (TypeScript) to take objects and read field by field into original object types.  Alternatively it appears that by dealing with 1 known object is how I can maximize my type usage and increase functionality.

Is taking data returned from services and transferring them to original objects something that is done as a common pattern in this ecosystem?

If so are there some write ups that explain common methods on doing that?

Comment: what does this mean "they're not in original object form"?  That looks like a JSON representation of the object, what were you expecting it to look like?

Comment: I think s/he means that it's untyped.

Comment: Another pattern is to avoid OOP entirely and keep your methods (functions, actually) separate from your data. Then you will have no problems calling your functions on returned data.

Comment: this is the pattern i was going to revert to, by putting everything in the service.  I get the impression both patterns are used widely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive an object from the backend, you should convert it from a JSON object into the appropriate model object.

This is what I usually do:

```
let order: Order = new Order(orderJsonObject);
```

To be able to do that, you need to update your constructor like this:

```
export class Order {
    readonly orderNumber: string;
    amount: number;
    shortCode: string;
    readonly dateCreated: string;

    constructor(data){
        if(data != null) {
          this.orderNumber = data.orderNumber;
          this.amount = data.amount;
          this.shortCode = data.shortCode;
          this.dateCreated = data.dateCreated;
        } else {
          this.orderNumber = cuid();
          this.dateCreated = moment().format();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the pattern I use and it has served us well so far.

Good luck

Comment: ok, i was aware of doing this, seemed like there was something more elegant.  Maybe its just that simple, glad to know its being used though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a 3rd party library for parsing json: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ta-json, this should work

```
import { JSON, JsonObject, JsonProperty } from "ta-json";
@JsonObject()
export class Order {
  @JsonProperty()
  readonly orderNumber: string;
  @JsonProperty()
  amount: number;
  @JsonProperty()
  shortCode: string;
  @JsonProperty()
  readonly dateCreated: string;

  constructor() {
    this.orderNumber = cuid();
    this.dateCreated = moment().format();
  }

  incrementAmount(): void {
    this.amount += 1;
  }
}

let order = new Order();
console.log(order.amount);
let toSave = JSON.stringify(order);

let fromJson = JSON.parse<Order>(toSave);
fromJson.incrementAmount();
console.log(fromJson.amount);
```